# The results returned are not highlighted

Tags: c#, solr, highlighting, solrnet

I searched for a field value but it is not returned as highlighted, meanwhile I want Solr not to display all document content, just a few rows.

**solrconfig:**

```
  <!-- Highlighting defaults -->
           <str name="hl">true</str>
           <str name="hl.fl">*</str>
           <str name="hl.requireFieldMatch">true</str>
           <str name="hl.preserveMulti">true</str>
           <str name="hl.encoder">html</str>
           <str name="hl.useFastVectorHighlighter">true</str>  
           <str name="hl.maxAnalyzedChars">-1</str>
           <str name="hl.simple.pre">&lt;b style="background:yellow"&gt;</str>
           <str name="hl.simple.post">&lt;/b&gt;</str>
           <str name="hl.fragmentsBuilder">colored</str>
           <str name="hl.fragsize">500</str>  <!-- for all fields with standard highlighting  -->
           <str name="f.content_en.hl.snippets">3</str>
           <str name="f.content_en.hl.fragsize">500</str>
           <str name="f.content_en.hl.alternateField">content_en</str>
           <str name="f.content_en.hl.maxAlternateFieldLength">500</str>
           <str name="f.content_ar.hl.snippets">3</str>
           <str name="f.content_ar.hl.fragsize">500</str>
           <str name="f.content_ar.hl.alternateField">content_ar</str>
           <str name="f.content_ar.hl.maxAlternateFieldLength">500</str>
           <str name="f.content_undf.hl.snippets">3</str>
           <str name="f.content_undf.hl.fragsize">500</str>
           <str name="f.content_undf.hl.alternateField">content_undf</str>
           <str name="f.content_undf.hl.maxAlternateFieldLength">500</str>
```

**managed-schema:**

```
 <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
   <field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <field name="subject" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="comments" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="author" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
   <field name="keywords" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="category" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="last_modified" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="stream_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="stream_size" type="tlong"  indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="created" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="extension" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="resourcename" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="xmptpg_npages" type="tlong" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="content_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <field name="suggest" omitNorms="true" type="text_suggest" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="shingle" omitNorms="true" type="text_shingle" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="content_en"  type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
     <field name="content_ar"  type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <!-- Main body of document extracted by SolrCell.
        NOTE: This field is not indexed by default, since it is also copied to "text"
        using copyField below. This is to save space. Use this field for returning and
        highlighting document content. Use the "text" field to search the content. -->
   <field name="content" type="text_en" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>


   <!-- catchall field, containing all other searchable text fields (implemented
        via copyField further on in this schema  -->
   <field name="text" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
 <!-- DEPRECATED: The defaultOperator (AND|OR) is consulted by various query parsers
  when parsing a query string to determine if a clause of the query should be marked as
  required or optional, assuming the clause isn't already marked by some operator.
  The default is OR, which is generally assumed so it is not a good idea to change it
  globally here.  The "q.op" request parameter takes precedence over this.
  -->
 <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/> 

  <!-- copyField commands copy one field to another at the time a document
        is added to the index.  It's used either to index the same field differently,
        or to add multiple fields to the same field for easier/faster searching.  

    Text fields from SolrCell to search by default in our catch-all field -->
   <copyField source="title" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="subject" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="comments" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="category" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="last_modified" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="author" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="description" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="keywords" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="content" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="resourcename" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="stream_name" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="extension" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="id" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="*_en" dest ="text" />
   <copyField source="*_ar" dest ="text" />
   <!-- suggest field for spell check dictionary -->
   <copyField source="title" dest="suggest"/>
   <copyField source="subject" dest="suggest"/>
   <copyField source="comments" dest="suggest"/>
   <copyField source="category" dest="suggest"/>
   <copyField source="last_modified" dest="suggest"/>
   <copyField source="author" dest="suggest"/>
   <copyField source="description" dest="suggest"/>
   <copyField source="keywords" dest="suggest"/>
   <copyField source="content" dest="suggest"/>
   <copyField source="stream_name" dest="suggest"/>
   <copyField source="extension" dest="suggest"/>
   <copyField source="*_undf" dest ="suggest" />
   <copyField source="*_en" dest ="suggest" />
   <copyField source="*_ar" dest ="suggest" />

   <!-- Shingle field for autocomplete Search-->
   <copyField source="title" dest="shingle"/>
   <copyField source="subject" dest="shingle"/>
   <copyField source="comments" dest="shingle"/>
   <copyField source="category" dest="shingle"/>
   <copyField source="last_modified" dest="shingle"/>
   <copyField source="author" dest="shingle"/>
   <copyField source="description" dest="shingle"/>
   <copyField source="keywords" dest="shingle"/>
   <copyField source="content" dest="shingle"/>
   <copyField source="stream_name" dest="shingle"/>
   <copyField source="extension" dest="shingle"/>
   <copyField source="*_undf" dest ="shingle" />
   <copyField source="*_en" dest ="shingle" />
   <copyField source="*_ar" dest ="shingle" />

   <!-- Create a string version of some fields for faceting -->
   <copyField source="extension" dest="extension_s"/>
   <copyField source="category" dest="category_s"/>
```

**Model:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using SolrNet.Attributes;

namespace SampleSolrApp.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        [SolrUniqueKey("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [SolrField("sku")]
        public string SKU { get; set; }

        [SolrField("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [SolrField("manu_exact")]
        public string Manufacturer { get; set; }

        [SolrField("cat")]
        public ICollection<string> Categories { get; set; }

        [SolrField("features")]
        public ICollection<string> Features { get; set; }

        [SolrField("price")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [SolrField("popularity")]
        public int Popularity { get; set; }

        [SolrField("inStock")]
        public bool InStock { get; set; }

        [SolrField("timestamp")]
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

        [SolrField("weight")]
        public double? Weight { get; set; }

        [SolrField("title")]
        public string title { get; set; }
        [SolrField("subject")]
        public string subject { get; set; }
        [SolrField("description")]
        public string description { get; set; }
        [SolrField("comments")]
        public string comments { get; set; }
        [SolrField("keywords")]
        public string keywords { get; set; }
        [SolrField("category")]
        public ICollection<string> category { get; set; }
        [SolrField("author")]
        public string author { get; set; }
        [SolrField("stream_name")]
        public string stream_name { get; set; }
        [SolrField("stream_size")]
        public string stream_size { get; set; }

        [SolrField("created")]
        public string created { get; set; }
        [SolrField("extension")]
        public string extension { get; set; }
        [SolrField("resourcename")]
        public string resourcename { get; set; }
        [SolrField("text")]
        public ICollection<string> text { get; set; }
        [SolrField("content_en")]
        public ICollection<string> content { get; set; }
        [SolrField("content_ar")]
        public ICollection<string> contentar { get; set; }
        [SolrField("suggest")]
        public ICollection<string> suggest { get; set; }
        [SolrField("shingle")]
        public ICollection<string> shingle { get; set; }
        [SolrField("xmptpg_npages")]
        public string xmptpg_npages { get; set; }

        [SolrField("last_modified")]
        public DateTime last_modified { get; set; }

        [SolrField("content_type")]
        public string content_type { get; set; }

    }

}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index(SearchParameters parameters)
        {
            try
            {
                var start = (parameters.PageIndex - 1) * parameters.PageSize;
                var matchingProducts = solr.Query(BuildQuery(parameters), new QueryOptions

                {
                    Highlight= new HighlightingParameters
                    {
                        Fragsize = 250,
                    Fields = new[] { "text" },
                    BeforeTerm = "<b>",
                    AfterTerm = "</b>",
                    Snippets = 10,

                    MaxAnalyzedChars = 100000,
                    },

                    FilterQueries = BuildFilterQueries(parameters),
                    //Rows = parameters.PageSize,
                    Rows = 10,
                    Start = 0,
                    //Start = 10,

                    OrderBy = GetSelectedSort(parameters),
                    SpellCheck = new SpellCheckingParameters(),
                    Facet = new FacetParameters
                    {
                        Queries = AllFacetFields.Except(SelectedFacetFields(parameters))
                                                                              .Select(f => new SolrFacetFieldQuery(f) { MinCount = 1 })
                                                                              .Cast<ISolrFacetQuery>()
                                                                              .ToList(),
                    },
                });

                var view = new ProductView
                {
                    Products = matchingProducts,
                    Search = parameters,
                    TotalCount = matchingProducts.NumFound,
                    Facets = matchingProducts.FacetFields,
                    DidYouMean = GetSpellCheckingResult(matchingProducts),
                };
                return View(view);
            }
            catch (InvalidFieldException)
            {
                return View(new ProductView
                {
                    QueryError = true,
                });
            }
        }
```

**View:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ProductView>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="SampleSolrApp.Helpers"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="SampleSolrApp.Models"%>

<asp:Content ID="indexHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <title>Hello World</title>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="indexContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <form method="get" action="<%= Url.Action("Index") %>">
        <%= Html.TextBox("q", Model.Search.FreeSearch) %>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        <% if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.DidYouMean)) { %>
        Did you mean <strong><em><a href="<%= Url.ForQuery(Model.DidYouMean) %>"><%= Model.DidYouMean%></a></em></strong>
        <% } %>
        <% if (Model.QueryError) { %> 
        <span class="error">Invalid query</span>
        <% } %>
    </form>

      <%using (Html.BeginForm("IndexAndUpload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, 
    new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" } )) 
 {
    Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    %>
    <fieldset style="display: block; margin: auto;">
        <legend>Upload a file</legend>

        <div class="editor-field">
           <input type="file" value="Browse" name="file" />
        </div>
       <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="submit" value="Index and Upload" style="display: block; margin: auto;"/>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
  <% } %>
 <!--   <div class="leftColumn">
        <% foreach (var f in Model.Search.Facets) { %>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <%= Html.SolrFieldPropName<Product>(f.Key) %>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="removeFacet" href="<%= Url.RemoveFacet(f.Key) %>"><%= f.Value %></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <% } %>

        <ul>            
            <% foreach (var f in Model.Facets) { %> 
            <li>
                <%= Html.SolrFieldPropName<Product>(f.Key) %>
                <ul>
                    <% foreach (var fv in f.Value) { %>
                    <li><a href="<%= Url.SetFacet(f.Key, fv.Key) %>"><%= fv.Key %></a> <span>(<%= fv.Value %>)</span></li>
                    <%} %>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <% } %>
        </ul>
    </div>
    -->
    <div class="rightColumn">

        <div>
            Sort by: 
            <% if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Search.Sort)) { %>
            <strong>Best match</strong>
            <% } else { %>
            <a href="<%= Url.RemoveParameters("sort") %>">Best match</a>
            <% } %>
            |
            <% if (Model.Search.Sort == "alphaNameSort") { %>
            <strong>Name</strong>
            <% } else { %>
            <a href="<%= Url.SetParameter("sort", "alphaNameSort") %>">Name</a>
            <% } %>
            |
            <% if (Model.Search.Sort == "price") { %>
            <strong>Price</strong>
            <% } else { %>
            <a href="<%= Url.SetParameter("sort", "price") %>">Price</a>
            <% } %>
            |

            <% if (Model.Search.Sort.NotNullAnd(s => s.StartsWith("random"))) { %> 
            <strong>Random</strong>
            <% } else { %>
            <a href="<%= Url.SetParameter("sort", "random_" + Html.RandomNumber()) %>">Random</a>
            <% } %>
        </div>

        <div>
            <% foreach (var p in Model.Products) { %>
            <div class="product">
                <div class="productName"><%= p.Name %></div>
                Price: <span class="price"><%= p.Price.ToString("C") %></span><br />
                Categories: <% Html.Repeat(p.Categories, cat => { %>
                    <a href="<%= Url.SetFacet("cat", cat) %>"><%= cat %></a><% }, () => {%>, <% }); %><br>
                 Content_Type: <span class="content-type"><%= p.content_type %></span><br />
                 Title: <span class="title"><%= p.title %></span><br />

                  Content-ar: <% Html.Repeat(p.contentar, ar => { %>
                    <a href="<%= Url.SetFacet("content_ar", ar) %>"><%= ar %></a><% }, () => {%>, <% }); %><br>  -->
                <%StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                  if(p.content != null)
                  { 
foreach(var c in p.content) {%>
                <%builder.Append(c); %>
                <%} }%>
          Content-en: <span class="content"><%= builder%></span><br />
                  Content-ar: <span class="contentar"><%= p.contentar%></span><br />

            </div>
            <%}
               %>
        </div>

        <% Html.RenderPartial("Pagination", new PaginationInfo {
            PageUrl = Url.SetParameter("page", "!0"),
            CurrentPage = Model.Search.PageIndex, 
            PageSize = Model.Search.PageSize,
            TotalItemCount = Model.TotalCount,
        }); %>

        <div class="pagesize">
            <% Html.Repeat(new[] { 5, 10, 20 }, ps => { %>
                <% if (ps == Model.Search.PageSize) { %>
                <span><%= ps%></span>
                <% } else { %>
                <a href="<%= Url.SetParameters(new {pagesize = ps, page = 1}) %>"><%= ps%></a>
                <% } %>
            <% }, () => { %> | <% }); %>
            items per page
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

**Solr Result from Solr Admin**

```
  {
      "responseHeader":{
        "status":0,
        "QTime":16,
        "params":{
          "q":"Arduino",
          "indent":"on",
          "wt":"json",
          "_":"1477734135388"}},
      "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"maxScore":0.79364794,"docs":[
          {
            "id":"a.pdf",
            "text":["a.pdf",
              "",
              "",
              "2014-10-09T19:45:46Z",
              "Arduino Programming Language",
              "C:\\Users\...,
              "Allison Okamura",
             Arduino Programming Language \n \n    \n Introduction to Haptics\n \n Arduino Programming Language\n \n Allison M. Okamura\nStanford University\n \n (optional material for beginning programmers) \n  \n \n   \n Programming Guidance\n \n Stanford University                                                                                         Introduction to Haptics                                                                                     ,
            "keywords":"",
            "subject":"",
            "last_modified":"2014-10-09T19:45:46Z",
            "title":"Arduino Programming Language",
            "content_type":"application/pdf",
            "stream_size":148285,
            "created":"Thu Oct 09 19:45:46 UTC 2014",
            "xmptpg_npages":23,
            "resourcename":"C:\\Users...,
            "language_s":"en",
            "content_en":[\n Arduino Programming Language \n \n    \n Introduction to Haptics\n \n Arduino Programming Language\n \n Allison M. Okamura\nStanford University,
      "spellcheck":{
        "suggestions":[],
        "collations":[]}}
```

**New Results**

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":24,
    "params":{
      "q":"arduino",
      "indent":"on",
      "wt":"json",
      "_":"1477737631856"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"maxScore":0.79364794,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"a.pdf",
        "text":["a.pdf",
          "",
          "",
          "2014-10-09T19:45:46Z",
          "Arduino Programming Language",
          "C:\\Users\\firas\\Desktop\\SampleSolrApp - true\\Content\\files\\a.pdf",
          "Allison Okamura",
          Introduction to Haptics\n \n Arduino Programming Language\n \n Allison M. Okamura\nStanford University\n \n (optional material for beginning programmers) ,
        "keywords":"",
        "subject":"",
        "last_modified":"2014-10-09T19:45:46Z",
        "title":"Arduino Programming Language",
        "content_type":"application/pdf",
        "stream_size":148285,
        "created":"Thu Oct 09 19:45:46 UTC 2014",
        "xmptpg_npages":23,
        "resourcename":"C:\\Users\\firas\\Desktop\\SampleSolrApp - true\\Content\\files\\a.pdf",
        "language_s":"en",
        "content_en":Arduino Programming Language \n \n    \n Introduction to Haptics\n \n Arduino Programming Language\n \n Allison M. Okamura\nStanford University\n \n (optional material for beginning programmers) ,
  "highlighting":{
    "a.pdf":{
      "text":["a.pdf   2014-10-09T19:45:46Z <b style=\"background:yellow\">Arduino</b> Programming Language C:\\Users\\firas\\Desktop\\SampleSolrApp - true\\Content\\files\\a.pdf Allison Okamura  style=\"background:yellow\">Arduino</b> Programming Language\n \n Allison M. Okamura\nStanford University\n \n (optional material for beginning programmers) \n  \n \n   \n Programming Guidance\n \n Stanford University                      "],
      "title":["<b style=\"background:yellow\">Arduino</b> Programming Language"],
      "language_s":["en"],
      "content_en":<b style=\"background:yellow\">Arduino</b> Programming Language \n \n    \n Introduction to Haptics\n \n <b style=\"background:yellow\">Arduino</b> Programming Language\n \n Allison M. Okamura\nStanford University\n \n (optional material for beginning programmers) \n  \n \n   \n Programming Guidance\n \n Stanford University                                                                                         Introduction to Haptics                                                ",
        "appropriate)\n• <b style=\"background:yellow\">Arduino</b>-specific tutorials\n \n In this class:\n• You will start from existing programs (sketches) and modify them\n• The complexity of the programming you will do is low\n• Debugging can be difficult because of the real-time nature of haptic \n \n interaction\n• You should learn by doing. There is little you can do to damage your \n \n Hapkit through programming mistakes! \n  \n \n   \n We will start by going through some examples at\n \n http:&#x2F;&#x2F;www.learn-c.org&#x2F;  \n  \n \n   \n <b style=\"background:yellow\">Arduino</b> Programming Language",
        "                         © Allison M. Okamura, 2014\n \n <b style=\"background:yellow\">Arduino</b> reference materials obtained from http:&#x2F;&#x2F;arduino.cc under a Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 License. \n \n Structure Variables Functions\n \n Basic syntax\n \n Arithmetic operators\n \n Control structures\n \n Comparison Operators\n \n Boolean Operators\n \n Constants\n \n Data types\n \n Scope\n \n Digital I&#x2F;O\n \n Analog I&#x2F;O\n \n Math\n \n Serial communication\n \n Defining your own \n  \n \n   \n <b style=\"background:yellow\">Arduino</b> Programming Language Components\n \n Stanford University "]}},
  "spellcheck":{
    "suggestions":[],
    "collations":[]}}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the raw results (the Solr response) ? You can remove managed-schema and model from the post since it won't affect highlighting, just ensure that you didn't edited manually the managed-schema, and that the fields for which you want highlighting are stored.

Comment: Thank you ericLavault, I posted the Solr result for the searching word Arduino, you can see that Solr returned the document that contain the word Arduino, but it didn't highlight it.

Comment: Ok but this is a screenshot of a view with processed results, I was talking about the raw output like you can see here : http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolJSON . It might help to investigate the "highlighting" part in the raw output to see if Solr is really missing highlighting or if it comes from the code that processes Solr response.

Comment: How can I do that?, can you learn me the way to see the raw results in SolrNet

Comment: The simplest way is to inspect it via [Solr Admin UI](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Overview+of+the+Solr+Admin+UI)

Comment: I searched for the word Arduino from solr admin, I just filled the q field area, and here are the raw output, hope is that what you meant.

Comment: Yes this is what I meant. But there is no highlight param in the request as you can see, I think you are not querying the good request handler (the one that is defined in solrconfig.xml where you have the highlighting params), specify it via `qt` in Solr admin.

Comment: You are right, the highlighting params are for browse request handler, I modified solrconfig and I added the highlighting parameters to select and query request handlers, after that the highlight params appears in solr admin (I posted it above), but still no change in the view.

Comment: Ok, Solr does return highlighted snippets from `text` field, so the issue is clientside between the controller and the view. In your controller try to log the snippets, something like :  
`foreach (var h in matchingProducts.Highlights[results[0].Id]) { 
  Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", h.Key, string.Join(", ", h.Value.ToArray()));
}`  If you got the snippet, you are pretty close, just bind it to the view for display, I'm not a solrnet expert so I cannot detail this part.